# How do i convert an array with varying size to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object array as shown below, The size of array is varying and the members of the array is also not static, 
How do I put all the data from the array in to a JSON object.

```js
Array:
[0] =>{ "Name": XYZ }
[1] =>{ "Gender":M }
[2] =>{ "DOB":09085672 }
[3] =>{ "City":London }
[4] =>{ "State":UK}
[5] =>{ "County":Chester }

JSON Output:
{
"Name":XYZ,
"Gender": M,
"DOB" : 09085672,
"City":London,
"State": UK,
"County":Chester
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge multiple objects in an array to a single object, you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array of objects into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [
  { "Name": 'XYZ' },
  { "Gender":'M' },
  { "DOB":09085672 },
  { "City": 'London' },
  { "State":'UK'},
  { "County":'Chester' }
]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...arr)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works :)